# why Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerMoved event handled property won't work in uwp?

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

what i have tried is?

```
   Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerMoved += OnCorePointerMoved1;
   Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerMoved += OnCorePointerMoved2;
        
    private void OnCorePointerMoved1(CoreWindow sender, PointerEventArgs args)
    {
        args.Handled = true;
    }

    private void OnCorePointerMoved2(CoreWindow sender, PointerEventArgs args)
    {
        
    }
```

when i run the code,the PointreMoved1 Event is triggered first.In that ,I had handled e.Handled=true .And then why PointerMoved2 Event also triggered.I don't know why this is happening?

Comment: Because you have added two methods to run on PointerMoved event. First one you've handled but the second one is still there .. don't think that just cuz it's same event so it will be handled and will stop on first one.

Comment: then.how can i stop the second one?I need to have two pointermoved events ,if one occurs ,other one won't occur.how to do that?

Comment: Remove the second one or use same `args.Handled = true;` in second method too..

Comment: The second method can say `if (args.Handled) return;` to skip processing if somebody else already handled the message.